# I have a excel file and want to delete some data before the first <br /> tag

Tags: database, excel, extract, vba

Donkeys are <a href="#">also</a> humans <br /> hello hello hello <br /> hey hey hey

I want to delete

"Donkeys are <a href="#">also</a> humans <br />"

--- > This Part

But only upto the first <br /> tag not for the scond or third ...

Need a function or anything

Its my first day with excel.

Comment: Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. It will help ppl with same problem to identify the correct solution:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA here is a sample code. I hope it helps.

```
Sub sample()

    Dim str_Val As String
    Dim start As Long
    str_Val = "Donkeys are <a href=""#"">also</a> humans <br /> hello hello hello <br /> hey hey hey"
    start = InStr(1, str_Val, "<br />", vbTextCompare) + Len("<br />")
    MsgBox Right(str_Val, Len(str_Val) - start)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this string is in Cell A1

If you want to include the first  <br />

`=MID(A1,FIND("<br />",A1,1),LEN(A1)-FIND("<br />",A1,1))`

If you don't

```
=MID(A1,FIND("<br />",A1,1)+7,LEN(A1)-FIND("<br />",A1,1))
```